# Why does these homeomorpic with the $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: general-topology

$Q) $ The usual topological space $(\mathbb{R}^2, T)$.  Say the subspace $(A_k ,T_k)$ in $(\mathbb{R}^2 ,T)$ for each $k \in \{ 1,2,3,4,5\}$. Find the $(A_k ,T_k)$ whose homeomorphic with the $(\mathbb{R}^2, T)$.

$A_1 = \{ (x,y) \vert x^2 + y^2 >1 \}$

$A_2 = \{ (x,y) \vert x^2 + y^2 <1 \}$

$A_3 = \{ (x,y) \vert -x \lt y \lt x \}$

$A_4 = \{ (x,y) \vert xy < 1 \}$

$A_5 = \mathbb{R}^2 - \{ (x,0) \vert 0 \leq x  \}$

In my point of view, the $A_1$ $\simeq$ $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$ and $A_2 \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$. Because if we either contract the boundary of $A_1$ to $(0,0)$ or expand the boundary of the $A_2$ to the outer directions for the the $A_2$ case. Vice versa the case $A_4$, with the similar method, $A_4 \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$.

But the problem is $A_3$ and $A_5$. The answer sheet claimed the both of them are homeomorphic with the $\mathbb{R}^2$.(I.,e.$A_3 \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$ & $A_5 \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$. ) I can't understand why these do hold. If we applying the same method above for the $A_5$ case, Is it have to be
homeomorphic with the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$ at most? Because it is not include the origin point at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning $A_3$: if you rotate anticlockwise that set around the origin by $\frac\pi4$ radians, you get the open first quadrant, which is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$ (consider the map $(x,y)\mapsto(e^x,e^y)$).

Concerning $A_5$: Consider the complex exponential map. Then$$\exp\left(\left\{z\in\Bbb C\mid-\frac\pi2<\operatorname{Im}z<\frac\pi2\right\}\right)=\Bbb C\setminus[0,\infty)$$and this gives you a homeomorphism between your set and $\left\{z\in\Bbb C\mid-\frac\pi2<\operatorname{Im}z<\frac\pi2\right\}$. And this set is homeomorphic to $\Bbb C$.